# Is Java 8 with Glassfish 2.1.1 possible?

Tags: java-8, sqljdbc, glassfish-2.x

As the title says, is it possible? Right now, we have Java 6 + sqljdbc4 + glassfish 2.1.1. We're planning on upgrading our Java 6 to Java 8 in order for Sqljdbc42.jar to work, because we are having JDBC Connectivity issue and the solution might be to upgrade to sqljdbc42. Please see Option 1 in this link:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2016/11/30/intermittent-jdbc-connectivity-issue-the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure-sockets-layer-ssl-encryption-error-sql-server-returned-an-incomplete-respons/

Of course some of you might say to upgrade Glassfish to a later version but in case is this is not an option, would errors occur? I found out that editing the asenv.bat will do the trick (http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/fixing-glassfish-jdk-path-problem-solved) but I'm not sure about the deeper problems we might face.

Thank you so much for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to be very brave (and have lots of free time) to try `jdk-8` on glassfish-2. While you can still download glassfish-2, the `Extended Support` support ends this year (2017). This is not even `Premium Support`, it's `Extended` meaning you have already gone too far by this time. I know this because of a client I used to work for that used glassfish-2.

There were multiple bugs and complaints reported or **the 3-rd and 4-th** versions with jdk-8, not even speaking of 2-nd. Unfortunately you should upgrade to something way more recent (and have a constant plan to upgrade from there still). Obviously you can try and change the jdk version and see what happens - but I bet you would be visiting this site way more often than you would want to.

The real reason why you should seriously consider upgrading is that not a lot of people can answer `deeper problems we might face`, because not a lot of people use this version.  Just my 0.02$.